# If the Hulk is a failed super soldier then why didn't Zemo kill him?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

Would the Hulk be dead because he is a failed super soldier and Zemo shot all of the other known super soldiers. Wouldn't he have shot Bruce too because he is a failed super soldier?

Comment: You may remember than Bruce was quite literally [on another planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor:_Ragnarok) by the time Baron Von Zima was shooting shooper sholdiers, and didn't return to earth until our buddy Helmut was locked up in prison.

Comment: Also, _failed?!?_ He brought half the universe’s population back from the dead! Feels like that’s at least partial credit.

Answer (score 26):

Hulk is not one of the failed Winter Soldiers. He is an attempt by Bruce Banner to recreate the super-soldier serum with Gamma Radiation, which caused his inner anger to manifest as a giant green monster. Hulk had been active for years prior to the events of Captain America: Civil War, so he couldn't have been in the tube to be killed by Zemo. Additionally, Hulk can't be killed with a single bullet to the brain. Banner tried that, and Hulk spat out the bullet.

Comment: Trying to kill the Hulk is a very good way to get yourself ***smashed***

Answer (score 21):

Multiple reasons really:

#### Hulk was not one of the Winter Soldiers

Hulk wasn't a Winter Soldier but rather a creation of his own. As such he wasn't in the chamber where Zemo killed the Winter Soldiers in *Captain America: Civil War*.

> **Helmut Zemo:** If it's any comfort, they died in their sleep. Did you really think I wanted more of you?
>
> <sub>*Captain America: Civil War*</sub>

#### Banner was MIA

At the time of *Captain America: Civil War*, when Zemo surfaced, Banner/Hulk were off world. No one knew where they were until Thor accidentally stumbles into him in *Thor: Ragnarok*. Hard to kill someone if you can't find them.

#### Hulk isn't exactly killable

Hulk has survived a lot, Thanos, Thor, Fenris, pretty much every broken bone, bullets as Banner, bullets as Hulk. He's not exactly the sort you can just kill.

> **Bruce Banner:** In case you needed to kill me, but you can't! I know! I tried! I got low. I didn't see an end, so I put a bullet in my mouth and the other guy spit it out! So I moved on. I focused on helping other people. I was good, until you dragged me back into this freak show and put everyone here at risk!
>
> <sub>*The Avengers*</sub>

#### Is it well known?

Hulk isn't exactly a normal super soldier. He's a mutated form. He doesn't really scream "super soldier" when you look at him. On top of that Banner didn't even know what he was working on. It's possible it wasn't really common knowledge that outside of S.H.I.E.L.D. that Banner was working on the formula and so that's essentially what he was.

Comment: Wasn't it Bruce's father that worked with super soldier serum? Bruce studied gamma rays afterward.

Comment: @Oni Bruce worked on the serum but wasn't told what it was... he did so using gamma rays. I don't think there's much at all on his father in the MCU.

Answer (score 1):

As you may remember from the end of *Civil War*, Zemo's ultimate goal wasn't actually eradication of super-soldier-serum recipients. It was to break up the Avengers.

He didn't want super-powered teams gallivanting across the world, triggering destruction (of places like his home city) and death (of people like his wife). While I'm sure he was happy to get the Winter Soldierettes  out of the picture, their storage facility was also a handy remote location to break the news to Tony that Steve's buddy killed his parents, and thus truly rend the Avengers asunder.

Hulk's location was, at that time, unknown, and in fact on the remote planet of Sakaar. Even if Zemo for some reason considered eliminating him too, it's difficult to see how he could have practically woven that into his main plan.