# Why doesn't Zemo care about Emil Blonsky's Abomination who's partly a super soldier?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

[If the Hulk is a failed super soldier then why didn't Zemo kill him?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/245650/if-the-hulk-is-a-failed-super-soldier-then-why-didnt-zemo-kill-him/245652) is one thing, but Emil Blonsky's Abomination actually got no less than **3 working** Super Solider injections ([first two here](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Abomination#Becoming_a_Super_Soldier) and [another here](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Abomination#Evening_the_Playing_Field))! Did Zemo not care (**Update:** despite his statement "Super soldiers cannot be allowed to exist" during *The Falcon and the Winter Soldier TV series*)?

At the time Blonsky was incarcerated is a special cell (initially the [Vault](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Vault) as mentioned in *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* and eventually [Damage Control Supermax Prison](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Damage_Control_Supermax_Prison) as actually seen in *She-Hulk: Attorney at Law*), but he did eventually escape to which Zemo probably would say "I told you so".

Is it because Blonsky **also** [already took the Hulk's blood while also having Gamma Radiation fired at him](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Abomination#Becoming_Abomination) and thus probably became unkillable? Or maybe because Zemo really believed in the American prison system?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you may remember from the end of *Civil War*, Zemo's ultimate goal wasn't actually eradication of super-soldier-serum recipients. It was to break up the Avengers.

He didn't want super-powered teams gallivanting across the world, triggering destruction (of places like his home city) and death (of people like his wife). While I'm sure he was happy to make sure the Winter Soldierettes were out of the picture, their storage facility was also a handy remote location to lure Tony and Steve, and break the news that Bucky killed Stark’s parents, thus truly rending the Avengers asunder.

While Zemo might have considered Abomination a similar potential threat, Blonksy was, as you say, effectively incarcerated at the time. Even later, when he did eventually escape his cell, he didn't cause damage — he participated in an underground fighting match under Wong's supervision, and set up a group therapy organisation for powered individuals. Not a lot of obvious Avengers-level risk to civilians there.

Comment: I guess Zemo didn't chase Isaiah Bradley either, so seems like he indeed cares only about active super soldiers. BTW, based on She-Hulk's season 1 ending, I'm not sure which of Wong and Blonsky is the supervisor of the other...

Comment: @user161260 He cares about splitting up the Avengers! That’s why it’s called _Captain America: Civil War_, not _Captain America: Super-Soldier Genocide Party!_

Comment: But: thank you for helping me get my shiny silver MCU badge.

Comment: Didn't you see The Falcon and the Winter Soldier TV series? _"Super soldiers cannot be allowed to exist."_

Comment: @user161260: I did! Beyond Isaiah Bradey it did not make much of an impression on me, but right, if he said that, he's got a super-soldier issue. I guess Abomination counts as a Hulk, not a super-soldier? Cos he's big and green?

Comment: Having re-read a summary of _Birdy-Bro and Snow-Dude_, I'm not sure when you'd expect Zemo to express an opinion about the Abomination. He's freed from one high-security prison to assist Bucky and Sam with their pursuit of the Flag Smashers, then put right back into another one by the Dora Milaje. While he manages to get a bomb deployed to finish off the Flag Smashers, he'd doesn't really have a lot of scope to start thinking about Hulks. He also seems to mainly want to avoid ongoing programs that create super-soldiers. Blonsky doesn't seem to be involved in or useful to anything like that.

Comment: @user161260 - Zemo doesn't go after just anyone.  He's a normal.  He knows it.  His targets are wannabe gods (or next best thing).  His very personal takedown against the Avengers consisted of calculation, manipulation, staying out of the line of fire, and even after all that ended with the assumption that whoever might be left would kill him.  Just because he's alive doesn't mean any given offense to his cause (like Blonsky) triggers him to go in guns blazing.  He'll pick his targets, think long term, and continue to be careful.

Comment: @Radhil Sure, although I think it’s also worth bearing in mind that his takedown against the Avengers almost ended in him committing suicide, and only T’Challa prevented that. At least at that point, he seemed to feel that he’d done enough towards his cause.

Comment: But again, then came _The Falcon and the Winter Soldier_ with "Super soldiers cannot be allowed to exist".

Comment: @user161260 Sure, I just think maybe you’re taking one sentence that he says in that show, and deciding that it alone is a complete and accurate summary of his entire motivation.

Comment: It's not just just 1 sentence, it's basically his monologue [from episode 3](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Baron_Zemo/Quote#Episode_1.03:_Power_Broker]) and _multiple_ dialogs [from episode 4](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Baron_Zemo/Quote#Episode_1.04:_The_Whole_World_Is_Watching).